# How to inject dependencies in app.config in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, url-routing

I've been getting errors when minifying my AngularJS app because manually injected dependencies aren't working how I'd expect. The following didn't work:

```
var config = app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {controller: 'PageCtrl', templateUrl: '../templates/home.html'});
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
});
config.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];
```

The only thing that worked is:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    ...
}]);
```

Why does the first dependency injection technique work for controllers but not configs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because app.config returns reference to the app (for chaining). This code works:

```
var config = function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {controller: 'PageCtrl', templateUrl: '../templates/home.html'})
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
};

config.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];
app.config(config);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/3196/

Comment: I was so fixated on the lines at the bottom, it took me awhile to realize you'd replaced the `app.config` with a standard function declaration.